# Batch's ERRORLEVEL works improperly and weird

Tags: batch-file, exit, errorlevel

I have a problem with the ERRORLEVEL in batch.
I paste here two code snippets to the exact problem and it can be reproducible.

What I haven't pasted here is that I tried the second code snippet with delayed expansion and the first with IF ERRORLEVEL 0 () instead of %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 but resulted the same problem unfortunately.

First trying with this code:

```
@ECHO OFF

call :CheckFileExists .\Database.db3

echo CheckFileExists returned %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo First check succeeded
    call :CheckFileExists .\dummy.txt

    echo CheckFileExists returned %ERRORLEVEL%
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        echo Second check succeeded
    ) ELSE (
        echo Second check failed
    )
) ELSE (
    echo First check failed
)

GOTO :eof

:CheckFileExists
IF exist %1 (
    echo INFO: Necessary file exists: %1
) ELSE (
    echo ERROR: Necessary file missing: %1
    EXIT /B 1
)
EXIT /B
```

And the outcome in cmd:

```
INFO: Necessary file exists: .\Database.db3
CheckFileExists returned 0
First check succeeded
ERROR: Necessary file missing: .\dummy.txt
CheckFileExists returned 0
Second check succeeded
```

Next I created two variables for each function call to hold the errorlevel but running it failures with the following code (and made echo on to find out where it fails):

```
@ECHO ON

call :CheckFileExists .\Database.db3

set error=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo CheckFileExists returned %error%
IF %error% == 0 (
    echo First check succeeded
    call :CheckFileExists .\dummy.txt
    set error2=%ERRORLEVEL%
    echo CheckFileExists returned %error2%
    IF %error2% == 0 (
        echo Second check succeeded
    ) ELSE (
        echo Second check failed
    )
) ELSE (
    echo First check failed
)

GOTO :eof

:CheckFileExists
IF exist %1 (
    echo INFO: Necessary file exists: %1
) ELSE (
    echo ERROR: Necessary file missing: %1
    EXIT /B 1
)
EXIT /B
```

For this the outcome in cmd:

```
call :CheckFileExists .\Database.db3

IF exist .\Database.db3 (echo INFO: Necessary file exists: .\Database.db3 )  ELSE (
echo ERROR: Necessary file missing: .\Database.db3
 EXIT /B 1
)
INFO: Necessary file exists: .\Database.db3

EXIT /B

set error=0

echo CheckFileExists returned 0
CheckFileExists returned 0
( was unexpected at this time.

        IF  == 0 (
```

I'm really stucked with this, could anyone help me out ? May be it can be something with the EXIT of the function ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
call :CheckFileExists .\Database.db3

echo CheckFileExists returned %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo First check succeeded
    call :CheckFileExists .\dummy.txt

    echo CheckFileExists returned !ERRORLEVEL!
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
        echo Second check succeeded
    ) ELSE (
        echo Second check failed
    )
) ELSE (
    echo First check failed
)

GOTO :eof

:CheckFileExists
IF exist %1 (
    echo INFO: Necessary file exists: %1
) ELSE (
    echo ERROR: Necessary file missing: %1
    EXIT /B 1
)
EXIT /B
```

or to use `IF ERRORLEVEL`

```
@ECHO OFF
call :CheckFileExists .\Database.db3

echo CheckFileExists returned %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo First check succeeded
    call :CheckFileExists .\dummy.txt

    call echo CheckFileExists returned %%ERRORLEVEL%%
    IF ERRORLEVEL  0 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo Second check succeeded
    ) ELSE (
        echo Second check failed
    )
) ELSE (
    echo First check failed
)

GOTO :eof

:CheckFileExists
IF exist %1 (
    echo INFO: Necessary file exists: %1
) ELSE (
    echo ERROR: Necessary file missing: %1
    EXIT /B 1
)
EXIT /B
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be working although I already tried with delayed expansion but the modification for the next ERRORLEVEL check the '!' marks make it work.

What and why is this exactly?

Comment: @Nepo - this is how delayed expansion works. If you are using `%` the variable will be expanded with the normal expansion despite the delayedExpansion is turned on. To access variables with delayed expansion you need both `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` and `!` instead of `%`

Comment: And why for the first usage of errorlevel we dont use the ! mark isntead of %?

Comment: no need for delayed expansion, because it's not in a code block.

Comment: @Nepo Open a command prompt window and run `set /?`. Delayed environment variable expansion is explained by the help output into the console window on an __IF__ condition and a __FOR__ loop. Then run `if /?` to get displayed the help for this command explaining the syntax `if errorlevel X` which should be always used in my opinion instead of `if %ERRORLEVEL% == X` or `if !ERRORLEVEL! == X` as working since MS-DOS unchanged up to Windows 10. See also Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Comment: In the IF ERRORLEVEL, the ERRORLEVEL substituted only at the line when its being read?

Comment: @Nepo - `IF ERRORLEVEL` in fact does not read the `%errorlevel%`  variable - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743/

Comment: And when the CheckFileExists exit with errorcode 1 or even 0, then which one is filled with it? This is still not clear for me to be honest.

Comment: Can this delayed expansion variable (!ERRORLEVEL!) be used multiple times in a more complex nested code ? Like 5 nested IF clauses.

Comment: @Nepo - yes you can. The difference between `!ERROELEVEL!` and `%ERRORLEVEL%` is that !errorlevel! will be substituted when the command is executed (i.e. after the script is parsed) and `%ERRORLEVEL%` will be substituted when the script is parsed (almost immidietely)